# css last selector (not last-child)

Tags: jquery, css

for example given this html

```
    <div class="my_div">a</div>
    <div class="my_div">b</div>
    <div class="my_div">c</div> 
    <div>other</div>
```

how can select last element from class `my_div`? `last-child` is not what I need.

That is, given this jquery selector

```
            $(".my_div:last").css({
                color: "#090"
            });
```

how can I write the same in pure css ?

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest solution be to add a class of last to the element you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible without modifying your markup. There is no `:last-of-class` selector in CSS.

Comment: You are right. I was sure that `.class:last-of-type` will do, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this

```
div:nth-last-child(2)
{
color:Green;
}​
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/EEDA5/3/)**

Comment: You misunderstand the question